# Linq to Entity and Loading EntitySets

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

This is my first attempt at understanding Linq to Entity coming from Net Tiers. Struggling with it but not understanding some of the logic behind it... for instance. 
When do I use:

```
Entity.EntitySet.Load()
```

and

```
context.Entity.Include("EntitySet").SingleOrDefault()
```

Also why does Include take a string and not an enum or sorts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF you have the concepts of Lazy loading and Eager loading.

- Lazy loading means you load the data the moment you need it. This is done trough the Load() method call.
- Eager loading means you already know upfront that you will need some data so you load it in the initial query trough Include(string).

Al tough Include takes a string this doesn't mean you can't extend this!

T4 is a nice thing. In a project I've worked on we created an EntityProperty class that contained static properties for all the Navigational properties on an entity. This way you would at least get a compile error if a property name changes.

If you really want to go one step further you could build a Include method that takes a Lambda and then rearrange the Expression tree before executing it to the QueryProvider. Then you would have nice static typing.

Comment: Just read more on Lazy Loading and Eager loading. The problem I have now, (perhaps another question), is that my entity object, now detached, cannot read Entity.EntitySets after using Include. Count is zero where as initial load showed 10. Do I have to reload every time I want the EntitySet values? (Hope this makes sense).

Comment: Could you update your starting post with a code example of what you're doing?

Comment: I think I have made a mistake in processing the webpage. I'm loading the EntitySets when I don't need to in the Page_Load. Long story but I think I need to raise another question in stackoverflow about the best way to check the number of entitysets with an already detached entity.

Answer (score 0):

Include is typically used for loading related tables. Load explicitly loads the requested entity.

String is used because MS chose to - not aware of any real limitation. Sort of how T4 solves the issue of string actions in MVC - maybe they will get around to improving/extending it to support stronger typing.

Comment: I sincerely hope they support stronger typing in the future.